# TYPO3 8.7 tx-news showinpreview field not visible

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I'm about to upgrade a page from TYPO3 6.2.30 to 8.7.0 but I can't find a way to use the "showinpreview" field in tx-news.

In the old tx-news 3.2.8 Version the Override sys_file_reference.php is called from /typo3conf/ext/news/Configuration/TCA/tx_news_domain_model_media.php

But in tx-news 5.3.3. I can only find the Override file.

In BE I only see News > Relations > Media File > Title and Description.

If I Change "showinpreview" in Table sys_file_reference to "1" the preview Picture Display in the FE.

I know that since 4.1.0 - 2016/01/27 the relation "tx_news_domain_model_media" will be removed. But is there any way to activate preview Images from the backend?

Thanks for any hints and for your great work!

Comment: Interesting, I got the same problem. TYPO3 update from 7.6 to 8.7 and now the "showinpreview"-checkbox is missing...

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a different way to use "imagePallettes" in TYPO3 8. The problem has already been solved in Github Master. https://github.com/georgringer/news

Comment: Thanks Paul, https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php does the Job after deleting /typo3temp Content.

Answer (score 0):

For display preview image in news list see attached image. you can do like this `News > Relations > Media File > check "Show in list views".`

[image]